# Convergence of $\partial_{x_j} u(x,t)$ when $u$ converges in $L^2$ norm.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I hope you can help me with this question.

We take $u(x,t)\in L^\infty_{loc}(\mathbb{R},H^1(M))\cap
Lip_{loc}(\mathbb{R},L^2(M))$, the derivatives $\partial_{x_j} u $ exist and are
continuous, i.e $\partial_{x_j} u(x,t) \rightarrow \partial_{x_j} u_0$, whenever
$u\rightarrow u_0$ in $L^2$ norm.

I wrote this argument that because the derivative exist and continuous that the convergence $u\rightarrow u_0$ implies the convergence in the derivatives.

But is this arguement complete, or do i need to add something here?

Thanks in advance.

P.S

$M$ is a compact manifold, and $x_j$ is a variable in the vector $x=(x_1,\ldots , x_n)$.
If you have further queries reagrding this question, ask me in the comments.

Comment: Please enhance your question. In particular: What is $M$, what is $x_j$? How do you proved the continuity of the derivative?

Comment: I added that $M$ is a compact manifold, and $x_j$ is a coordinate in the vector $x$. The continuity of the derivative is because u is  Lipschitzian, I am not sure if this is valid.

Comment: The question is still not perfect: If you write $u(x,t) \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R},H^1(M))$ it looks like $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in M$, but this seems not to be the case. Moreover, which $L^2$-norm do you refer to in the second paragraph?

Comment: Both convergences are in L^2 norm. You should replace the roles of t and x. t is in R and x in M.

Answer (score 0):

This will not hold. Take your favorite sequence $\{v_n\}\subset H^1(M)$ and $v \in H^1(M)$ such that $\{v_n\}$ converges towards $v$ in $L^2(M)$, but not in $H^1(M)$.

Now, set $u_n(t,x) = v_n(x)$ and $u(t,x) = v(x)$. This yields $u_n \to u$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R};L^2(M))$, but $\partial_{x_j} u_n \not\to \partial_{x_j} u$ in the same space.

Comment: I didnt ask for convergence of the derivative to the function. How did you think of it?

Comment: This was a typo.

Comment: But the function $u_n$ should be in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R},H^1(M))$ and not in $L^\infty ( \mathbb{R}, L^2(M))$ as you wrote.

Comment: $u_n \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R},H^1(M))$ since $v_n \in H^1(M)$.